# How to create SQL statement for the following result?

Tags: sql, database, hana

I have a table with following contents -

[image: Table]

I am trying to create 4 columns out of this called as follows -

- Risk
- Risk_Count
- Revenue
- Revenue_Count

The following SQL query gets me the desired 4 columns but it also produces NULL values.

```
select CASE when "BUCKET"='High Revenue' OR "BUCKET"='Low Revenue' OR "BUCKET"='Medium Revenue' then BUCKET end as Revenue,
CASE when "BUCKET"='High Revenue' OR "BUCKET"='Low Revenue' OR "BUCKET"='Medium Revenue' then CUSTOMER_COUNT end as Revenue_count,
 CASE when "BUCKET"='High Risk' OR "BUCKET"='Low Risk' OR "BUCKET"='Medium Risk' then BUCKET end as Risk,
  CASE when "BUCKET"='High Risk' OR "BUCKET"='Low Risk' OR "BUCKET"='Medium Risk' then CUSTOMER_COUNT end as Risk_count
FROM "TABLE_NAME"
```

Result -

[image: Output]

How to remove the NULL values and have the results in one row so ideally the output should contain 3 rows with 4 columns.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `SUM()` or `MAX()`:

```
select MAX(CASE when "BUCKET"='High Revenue' OR "BUCKET"='Low Revenue' OR "BUCKET"='Medium Revenue' then BUCKET end) as Revenue,
       MAX(CASE when "BUCKET"='High Revenue' OR "BUCKET"='Low Revenue' OR "BUCKET"='Medium Revenue' then CUSTOMER_COUNT end) as Revenue_count,
       MAX(CASE when "BUCKET"='High Risk' OR "BUCKET"='Low Risk' OR "BUCKET"='Medium Risk' then BUCKET end) as Risk,
       MAX(CASE when "BUCKET"='High Risk' OR "BUCKET"='Low Risk' OR "BUCKET"='Medium Risk') then CUSTOMER_COUNT end as Risk_count
FROM "TABLE_NAME"
```

Then you can simplify the logic using `IN` or `LIKE`:

```
select max(case when "BUCKET" in ('High Revenue', 'Low Revenue', 'Medium Revenue') then BUCKET end) as Revenue,
       max(case when "BUCKET" in ('High Revenue', 'Low Revenue', 'Medium Revenue') then CUSTOMER_COUNT end) as Revenue_count,
       max(case when "BUCKET" in ('High Risk', 'Low Risk', 'Medium Risk') then BUCKET end) as Risk,
       max(case when "BUCKET" in ('High Risk', 'Low Risk', 'Medium Risk') then CUSTOMER_COUNT end as Risk_count
FROM "TABLE_NAME";
```

I would also advise you to get rid of the double quotes around the identifiers.  Only quote identifiers when you really have to -- and then choose identifiers (such as the ones you have) that do not need to be quoted.

EDIT:

I think you want:

```
select max(case when bucket like '%Revenue' then BUCKET end) as Revenue,
       max(case when bucket like '%Revenue' then CUSTOMER_COUNT end) as Revenue_count,
       max(case when bucket like '%Risk' then BUCKET end) as Risk,
       max(case when bucket like '%Risk' then CUSTOMER_COUNT end) as Risk_count
FROM "TABLE_NAME"
GROUP BY LEFT(bucket, 3)  -- sufficient to distinct high/medium/low
```

Comment: Hi, ended up with the following error - ` inconsistent datatype: only numeric type is available for SUM/AVG/STDDEV/VAR function: `

Comment: @BoudhayanDev . . . Your values look like numbers.  If they are strings, you should use `max()` or `min()`.

Comment: I used max and it printed the row with Medium revenue and Medium risk, understandably because that's the row with highest value

Comment: @BoudhayanDev . . . Now I understand better what you want.  I added another approach.

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly how I wanted. However, can you explain what does LEFT(bucket, 3) do ?

Comment: @BoudhayanDev . . . It extracts the first three characters and uses that to define the rows in the result set.  The first three characters are sufficient for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and max() to get the desired results as you cannot use sum() on alpha-numeric fields - it will throw an error.

```
select Revenue, Revenue_Count, Risk, Risk_Count from 
(
select 
     case 
          when bucket like 'High%' then 1
          when bucket like 'Low%' then 2
          else 3
     end, 
     max(case when bucket like '%Revenue%' then bucket else null end) as Revenue,
     max(case when bucket like '%Revenue%' then customer_count else null end) as Revenue_Count,
     max(case when bucket like '%Risk%' then bucket else null end) as Risk,
     max(case when bucket like '%Risk%' then customer_count else null end) as Risk_Count
 from public.table_name 
 group by 
    case 
       when bucket like 'High%' then 1
       when bucket like 'Low%' then 2
       else 3
    end
  order by 1    
) x;
```

Comment: Running into this erro r- Could not execute 'select Revenue, Revenue_Count, Risk, Risk_Count from ( select case when "Bucket" like 'High%' then ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [260]: invalid column name: Bucket: line 5 col 16 (at pos 94)

Comment: I ran this in PostgreSQL which required the quotes on the field names.  Remove them and you should be fine.

Comment: Fixed the issue with quoted field names.  Appears this happens in PostgreSQL if you use uppercase letters.  I renamed the fields to lowercase and removed the quotes.

Comment: Im not using Postgres. Hana instead. and quotes doesnt matter

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with UNION:

```
select 
  'High Revenue' REVENUE,
  (select CUSTOMER_COUNT from TABLE_NAME where BUCKET = 'High Revenue') REVENUE_COUNT,
  'High Risk' RISK,
  (select CUSTOMER_COUNT from TABLE_NAME where BUCKET = 'High Risk') RISK_COUNT
union all
select 
  'Medium Revenue' REVENUE,
  (select CUSTOMER_COUNT from TABLE_NAME where BUCKET = 'Medium Revenue') REVENUE_COUNT,
  'Medium Risk' RISK,
  (select CUSTOMER_COUNT from TABLE_NAME where BUCKET = 'Medium Risk') RISK_COUNT
union all
select 
  'Low Revenue' REVENUE,
  (select CUSTOMER_COUNT from TABLE_NAME where BUCKET = 'Low Revenue') REVENUE_COUNT,
  'Low Risk' RISK,
  (select CUSTOMER_COUNT from TABLE_NAME where BUCKET = 'Low Risk') RISK_COUNT
```

See the MySql [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3FXWFfRC6ihXJhMwU6KAqK/0)
See the Postgress [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3FXWFfRC6ihXJhMwU6KAqK/1)

Comment: firstly, you have missed -- from TABLE_NAME before union all statements. and secondly, even after applying the changes doesnt show up the desired result. Instead it shows 0 rows

Comment: I just edited with a demo, check it. You don't need `from TABLE_NAME`.

Comment: Could not execute 'select 'High Revenue' REVENUE, (select CUSTOMER_COUNT from TABLE_NAME where ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "union": line 6 col 1 (at pos 269)

Comment: The code above works for both MySql and Postgress. Where do you execute this code?

Comment: Using HANA sql                                          .

Comment: Why did you tag with MySql and Postgress?

Comment: My bad. removed it

Comment: I don't know the differences between mysql and hana. If you do, make any change you need.